# Google Cloud Endpoints with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

I was not able to find documentation about how to connect GCF with Google Cloud Endpoints. As I understand Google Cloud Endpoints can be configured to access internal cloud resources. It is not clear how to use load balancer with Endpoints service as well.

In the [Building Scalable Web Apps with Cloud Datastore article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/building-scalable-web-apps-with-cloud-datastore#scenario_3_function-based_infrastructure) it indicates that you should be able to configure a direct connection from Cloud Endpoints to Cloud Functions. There is no indication that you would need to have any Compute Engine or other infrastructure between them. Is there any documentation or tutorial on how to connect Cloud Endpoints to Cloud Functions? Did somebody manage to connect those two services?

Comment: It may be possible using ESP (Extensible Service Proxy). It is basically a custom Nginx server that could use LUA and subrequests to trigger a cloud function. https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp

Answer (score 8):

At this time, there is no way to connect GCF with Endpoints. Sorry about that!

Comment: This keeps me away from using GCF. Authorization should not be a part of my function itself. I also don't want my GCF to be DDoS-ed, making me to pay big buck for something I am unable to protect.

Comment: AWS has API Gateway to manage their Lambda Functions, in a similar way does Google has anything to manage cloud functions?

Comment: There is an EAP starting on Cloud Endpoints for GCF; see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-endpoints/gwmuJNEgfAI/SIgtjv9VBgAJ for more details.

Comment: Now it's possible

Answer (score 3):

The pair of Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Cloud Functions and AWS API Gateway and AWS lambda are not same.

Google Cloud Endpoints monitor your existing API analytics and limits its usage via API Credentials.

So to link your Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Cloud Functions, you have to use Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine to connect them.

Comment: This is how we did that. Via Compute Engine and nginx.

Comment: Standing up a Compute Engine or App Engine instance to front Cloud Functions seems antithetical to the point of Cloud Functions.